# Iterating through array lists

Tags: java

I'm creating a lottery game where it checks if the user guessed 2, 3, 4, or 5 numbers out of the random lottery numbers, then prints a message. Lottery numbers are from 1 - 100 printed 10 times and users guess 5 numbers. I have tried `for` loops and if statements and it doesn't print the right message out. Don't mind the variables as I'm just testing out to see what works. My question is, how do I check if the user guessed 2 , 3 , 4 or 5 numbers correctly? Here is my code.

```
    // first way to check if user guessed correctly 
    
    int  x,y;
    
    for ( int i = 4; i< numbers.length; i++) {
        x = numbers[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < lottery.length; j++) {
            y = lottery[j];
            
            if (x == y) {
                System.out.println("You guessed 5 numbers");
            }
            for ( i = 3; i< numbers.length; i++ ) {
                x = numbers[i];
                
                if ( x == y) {
                    System.out.println("You guessed 4 numbers");
                }
                for ( i = 2; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                    x = numbers[i];
                    
                    if ( x == y) {
                        System.out.println("You guessed 3 numbers");
                    }
                    for ( i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                        x = numbers[i];
                        
                        if ( x == y) {
                            System.out.println("You guessed 2 numbers");
                        }
                      }
                    }
                }
  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lottery numbers are generated from 1 - 100 printed 10 times .User can guess 5 times out of 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int count = 0;
        int[] lottery = new int[5];
        int[] input = new int[5];

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 5 number: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            input[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < lottery.length; i++) {
            int random = r.nextInt(10); // Upper bound of random generator = 10.
            lottery[i] = random;
            System.out.print(lottery[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lottery.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
                if (lottery[i] == input[j]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (count == 0) {
            System.out.println("\nToo bad, you have 0 correct guess. Try again!");
        } else if (count == 1) {
            System.out.println("\n1 number guessed correctly! You won $1000!");
        } else if (count == 2) {
            System.out.println("\n2 number guessed correctly! You won $6000!");
        } else {
            // Add condition
        }
    }
```

This will receive 5 random numbers and store it in `lottery` array. The program will prompt user for 5 input numbers, store it in `input` and compare `lottery[i]` with each numbers in `input`. If two numbers are equal, increment `count`. Example run:

```
Enter 5 number: 
1 2 3 4 5
7 2 5 9 1 
2 number guessed correctly! You won $6000!
```

Note that if the random number generator creates two or more duplicate numbers, the `count` will increases as well. It's an edge case, but I think you can Google for it if you want the improvement.

Implementing this using `ArrayList` is also a lot more simple because `ArrayList` has the method `contains()` that will check if it has such elements. We can use  a trivial `if-else` loop for it. I assume OP's homework has a constraint of using `Array` and therefore not using this method.

Comment: In my code I don't think order really matters. For example, at `lottery[0] = 2`, it will check for every single numbers in user's `input` from `[0]` to `[4]`  and it will do the same for the rest of `lottery[]`. Which means that no matter which order you input, it will always correctly increment `count` if the number matches.

Comment: no the order doesn't matter at all , the program just checks if any number was guessed

Comment: this code is the one I would use but instead of just printing " correct numbers guessed" I want to print for example if one number was guessed : 'You guessed one number , you win €1,000" or if two numbers were guessed : "You guessed two numbers , you win €6,000" . Do I need to repeat the for loop for each statement or just set guess = 0; and use if statements?

Comment: Thank you so much.I have been stuck at this for ages.Its actually funny I tried switch statements too I just didn't set the count to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a complete and fully working example program. It uses `ArrayLists` to store the different numbers. With `shuffle`, the lottery numbers are mixed. After all numbers were shuffled, the first 5 elements are taken from the lottery numbers and declared as the winning numbers. **All winning numbers are uniqe.**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LotteryGame {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final int N = 5; // Number of winning lottery numbers.

        ArrayList<Integer> winningNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> userNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Are also 5 numbers (5 out of 1 to 100 lottery
                                                                    // game).
        ArrayList<Integer> lotteryNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // Insert user numbers (user's tips).
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter 5 numbers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            userNumbers.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }

        System.out.println("\nUser's Tips:\n" + userNumbers);

        // Generating the different numbers.
        for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) { // Lottery game: Numbers from 1 to 100.
            lotteryNumbers.add(i);
        }

        // System.out.println("\nOriginal Lottery Numbers:\n" + lotteryNumbers);

        // Shuffle the lottery numbers randomly.
        Collections.shuffle(lotteryNumbers);

        // System.out.println("\nShuffled Numbers:\n" + lotteryNumbers);

        // Retrieve the N-th first elements from the ArrayList (all numbers are uniqe).
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            winningNumbers.add(lotteryNumbers.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println("\nWinning Numbers are:\n" + winningNumbers);

        // Checking the correct guessed numbers.
        int count = 0;
        for (int userTip : userNumbers) {
            if (winningNumbers.contains(userTip)) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        // Print out fi the user has won a money price or not.
        if (count == 0) {
            System.out.println("\nSorry, no numbers guessed!");
        } else if (count == 1) {
            System.out.println("\nYou guessed ONE number, you win $1,000");
        } else if (count == 2) {
            System.out.println("\nYou guessed TWO numbers, you win $6,000");
        } else if (count == 3) {
            System.out.println("\nYou guessed THREE numbers, you win $10,000");
        } else if (count == 4) {
            System.out.println("\nYou guessed FOUR numbers, you win $20,000");
        } else if (count == 5) {
            System.out.println("\nYou guessed FIVE numbers, you win $30,000");
        }
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
Please Enter 5 numbers: 
3 7 33 93 43

User's Tips:
[3, 7, 33, 93, 43]

Winning Numbers are:
[54, 31, 48, 64, 82]

Sorry, no numbers guessed!
```

Comment: Thank you.I want to print for example if one number was guessed : 'You guessed one number , you win €1,000" or if two numbers were guessed : "You guessed two numbers , you win €6,000".That is my main problem, I don't know how to print a different message for every statement

Comment: @MelissaSpivacenco I have changed the output of the program. With if, else if's I check the different conditions, and if a specific condition is met, I output the appropriate text.

Answer (score -1):

Convert arrays to lists and do the checks

```
 List<Integer> userNumbers = Arrays.stream(numbers).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
 List<Integer> lotteryNumbers = Arrays.stream(lottery).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());


 int count = 0;
 for(int i=0; i<userNumbers.size();i++){
     if(lotteruNumbers.contains(i)){
          count++
     }
 }

 System.out.println("You've guessed"+ count+ " numbers");
```

Comment: ` i<userNumbers` is an invalid expression, you can not compare lists and numbers using `<`. There is no need to convert to lists in the first place, you gain nothing by doing that, and depending on the lottery used your result is utterly incorrect.

Comment: You can leave these as ArrayLists and use the same logic because the methods ```size()```, ```contains()``` and ```get()``` exist.